Fix the error fatal error : CreateProcess: No such file or directory compilation terminated
I don't know English very well. I apologize if there was a problem in the text.
I was coding with the program when this error was shown by the compiler for the program being written and previous programs (which were running).

{PS D:\ostadataeian> cd "d:\ostadataeian" ; if ($?) { g++ 7.cpp -o 7 } ; if ($?) { .\7 }
collect2.exe: fatal error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
PS D:\ostadataeian> }

I tried several times in new files or new folders or changed the names of the folders to English, but it didn't work.
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num[99];
    int n, m = 0,o=0;
    cin >> n;
    
    while (m<n){
        
        if (m == 0){
            num[m] = 0;
        }
        
        else if((num[m-1]-m)> 0){
            num[m] = num[m - 1] - m;
        }
        
        else {
            num[m] = num[m -1] + m;
        }
        
        for(int o = 0; o < m ; o++){
                if(num[o]==num[m])
                {
                    num[m] = num[m-1] + m;
                }
            }
            
        if (m == n-1)
            cout << num[m];
        else{
            cout << num[m] << ",";
        }
        m++;
    }
    return 0;
}


It sounds like you may have accidentally broken the compiler, either by deleting/renaming some component or by removing the compiler from PATH. You may consider reinstalling the compiler to see if the issue goes away.
